# How do you clear your call logs history in android?

Tags: android, phone-call, calllog

How can you clear the entire call log history in android? Currently i have this code that can only clear a particular call log

```
public void DeleteCallLogByNumber(String number) {   
    String queryString="NUMBER="+number; 
    this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,queryString,null);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Not ideal so a comment not an answer but you could always read all call log entries and delete them in this way...

Comment: Try this? 
@Rpc(description = "Deletes an Entry from call Log ") 
public void deleteAnEntryFromCallLog(String number) 
{ 
try 
{ 
Uri CALLLOG_URI = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"); 
mService.getContentResolver().delete(CALLLOG_URI,CallLog.Calls.NUMBER +"=?",new String[]{number}); 
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{ 
e.getMessage(); 
} 
}

Comment: @AlexanderWigmore that doesnt work

Comment: if you can delete one, then you can delete them all. just query the call log to get all the entries then delete them one by one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to do it with this, It's been a while though. Not sure if this still works.

```
getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null) ;
```

EDIT: Please note I am not certain that the platform designers intended for apps to be able to delete the call log [See this dev blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html). So while this does technically work please take this as a fair warning that it may at any point change and break what you are trying to build.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete all with a single API call.

You can, however, delete them one-by-one (as mentioned in the comments) by looping through them all. To do that, you'll want to [use a `Cursor`](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/4/). Keep in mind: that link only wipes out calls of less than 60 seconds, so you'll have to modify the `Cursor` creation to delete all calls instead.

Also note: For APIs 11+, you should be using [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) instead of `managedQuery(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String queryString="DURATION >= 0"; 
this.getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, queryString, null);
```