# How to Clear Call Logs on Android 4.3?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, calllog

I am developing an android app trying to clear the call logs as in below code.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

This is working on all phones but not on Galaxy nexus with Android 4.3. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please suggest how to clear call logs in version 4.3 and above.Thanks!

Comment: see this developers blog post... http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786800/how-do-you-clear-your-call-logs-history-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following this will delete all your call logs from the phone:

```
getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null) ;
```

then:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

to your manifest.